# Intent not passing correct information

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-sqlite

Im using intents to pass the noteId from my database to a different activity for displaying the information it was working and i went to work on another part of the project and now it seems to only pass one value  and from playing about i have found that seems to be whatever is the next highest object on the ListView. Sorry if this is badly worded, Im not very good at explaining these things

ViewNote Class

```
package com.hardy.passnotes;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewNote extends Activity {

    EditText NewNoteTitle;
    EditText NewNoteContent;
    TextView tvNoteId;
    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_note);
        NewNoteTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETNewNoteTitle);
        NewNoteContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETNewNoteContent);

        Intent n = getIntent();
        String NoteId = n.getStringExtra("noteId");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), NoteId,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        HashMap<String, String> NoteList = dbTools.getNoteInfo(NoteId);


        if(NoteList.size() != 0)
        {
            setTitle("Note: " + NoteList.get("noteTitle"));
            NewNoteTitle.setText(NoteList.get("noteTitle"));
            NewNoteContent.setText(NoteList.get("noteContent"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.view_note, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_Editnote:
            tvNoteId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NoteId);
            String NoteValue = tvNoteId.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),EditNote.class);
            intent.putExtra("noteId", NoteValue);
            startActivity(intent);

        case R.id.action_DelNote:
            Intent intent1 = getIntent();
            String NoteId = intent1.getStringExtra("noteId");

            dbTools.deleteNote(NoteId);
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(),MyNotes.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

MyNote Class:

```
package com.hardy.passnotes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyNotes extends ListActivity {

    DBTools dbTools = new DBTools(this);
    TextView tvNoteId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_notes);
        Log.i("Tag", "OnCreate Started As Normal");
        setTitle("My Notes");



        ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>> NoteList = dbTools.getAllNotes();

        if(NoteList.size() != 0)
        {
            ListView listView = getListView();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    tvNoteId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NoteId);
                    String NoteValue = tvNoteId.getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyNotes.this,ViewNote.class);
                    intent.putExtra("noteId", NoteValue);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    Log.i("Tag", "if Started As Normal");
                }

            });



        ListAdapter Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyNotes.this,NoteList,R.layout.notes_list, new String[]{"noteId","noteTitle",}, new int[]{R.id.NoteId,R.id.NoteTitle}  ); 
        setListAdapter(Adapter);
        Log.i("Tag", "Arrey Started As Normal");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_notes, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_Add:
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CreateNote.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance been searching around and debugging for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think the problem is that you use the `findViewById()` method inappropriately in your `onItemClick` listener.

**You should use:**

```
tvNoteId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.NoteId);
```

Notice that I call the `findViewById` method on the `view` given by the `onItemClick` method because you want to find the view with the id `NoteId` from the pressed item and not from the entire's activity content view.. the way you do it will search in the content view of your activity for the first id equal with `NoteId` ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your note get deleted on the moment edit is clicked from the options menu.
At the end of    case R.id.action_Editnote    nothing is returned nor break is called so    case R.id.action_Delnote    will be executed as well. This is where you delete the note from your database.

Comment: I overlooked this thanks for pointing it out but I still have the main issue listed in the post

Answer (score 0):

In your switch, put a break:

```
    switch (item.getItemId())
            {
            case R.id.action_Editnote:
                tvNoteId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NoteId);
                String NoteValue = tvNoteId.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(),EditNote.class);
                intent.putExtra("noteId", NoteValue);
                startActivity(intent);
break;

            case R.id.action_DelNote:
                Intent intent1 = getIntent();
                String NoteId = intent1.getStringExtra("noteId");

                dbTools.deleteNote(NoteId);
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(),MyNotes.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
break;

            }
```